# Ninject.MVC3 + MediumTrust = Security Exception

Tags: ninject, bootstrapper, asp.net-mvc-4

1. I created a new project of type Asp.net MVC 4
2. I installed the package via Ninject.MVC3 NuGet `Install Package Ninject.MVC3`
3. When running the project, security error:

## Error

> Server Error in '/MediumTrustSample' Application.
>
> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 20:
>   DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule)); Line
>   21:
>   DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(HttpApplicationInitializationModule));
>   Line 22:             bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel); Line 23:
>   } Line 24:
>
> Source File: C:\Users\Riderman_2\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\MediumTrustSample\MediumTrustSample\App_Start\NinjectMVC3.cs
>   Line: 22
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.]
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.SpecialDemand(PermissionType
>   whatPermission, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +0
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand(PermissionType
>   permissionType) +30
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +281
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +38    Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.GetParentDefinition(MethodInfo
>   method, BindingFlags flags) in ExtensionsForMemberInfo.cs:145
>   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.IsDefined(PropertyInfo
>   element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) in
>   ExtensionsForMemberInfo.cs:173
>   Ninject.Selection.Heuristics.StandardInjectionHeuristic.ShouldInject(MemberInfo
>   member) in StandardInjectionHeuristic.cs:47
>   Ninject.Selection.<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_2(IInjectionHeuristic h) in Selector.cs:92    System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate) +149
>   Ninject.Selection.Selector.b_*1(PropertyInfo
>   p) in Selector.cs:92
>
>   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +156
>
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,
>   IEnumerable`1 collection) +552
>
>   Ninject.Selection.Selector.SelectPropertiesForInjection(Type type) in
>   Selector.cs:89
>
>   Ninject.Planning.Strategies.PropertyReflectionStrategy.Execute(IPlan
>   plan) in PropertyReflectionStrategy.cs:60
>
>   Ninject.Planning.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetPlan>b__1(IPlanningStrategy s)
>   in Planner.cs:68
>
>   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1
>   series, Action`1 action) in ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:23
>
>   Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan(Type type) in Planner.cs:70
>
>   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in Context.cs:180
>
>   Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7(IContext context) in
>   KernelBase.cs:375
>
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +238
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +299
>
>   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext
>   parent) in Target.cs:179
>
>   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in
>   Target.cs:147
>
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext
>   context, ITarget target) in StandardProvider.cs:97
>
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +110
>
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +488
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +104
>
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
>   in StandardProvider.cs:81    Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in
>   Context.cs:157    Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7(IContext context)
>   in KernelBase.cs:375
>
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +238
>
>   System.Linq.d*_b1`1.MoveNext() +296
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +282
>   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[]
>   parameters) in ResolutionExtensions.cs:37
>   Ninject.Web.Mvc.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback)
>   in Bootstrapper.cs:72
>   MediumTrustSample.App_Start.NinjectMVC3.Start() in
>   C:\Users\Riderman_2\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\MediumTrustSample\MediumTrustSample\App_Start\NinjectMVC3.cs:22
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

## Question

**How to use Ninject.MVC3 with MediumTrust?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go and get the medium trust version: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/downloads

Comment: how could we import this into the Solution? I use the nuget package manager normally. But this version is not available in the nuget library!